# EF Automapper Parents child is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I'm trying to read data from our database using entity framework and as the project already uses Automapper to convert from entities to Dtos it would make sense use Automappers Queryable Extensions to make life a bit easier. I'm using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version 3.1.9.0

The problem is the returned array of BundleMetaDataDt.child is always null.
The query below returns plenty of data, but every BundleMetaDataDtos child value is null.

I have tried:

- .Include(b => b.ChildBundle) before Where statement
- .ForMember(dest => dest.ChildBundle, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ChildBundleId))
- .MaxDepth(2)

Classes: (There is more fields than shown below)

```cs
public partial class Bundle
{
  public Guid? ChildBundleId { get; set; }
  public Bundle ChildBundle { get; set; }
}

public class BundleMetaDataDto
{
  [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 15)]
  public BundleMetaDataDto ChildBundle { get; set; }
}
```

Map:

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<Bundle, BundleMetaDataDto>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.ChildBundle, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ChildBundle))
```

Query:

```cs
var bundles = context.Bundles
  .Where(bundle => bundle.ChildBundle != null)
  .ProjectTo<BundleMetaDataDto>(EntityConverter.MapperConfiguration)
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: The `MapFrom` is useless. You need to set `RecursiveQueriesMaxDepth`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thanks got it working, but I have a questing, in what way is MapFrom useless, should I be using something else?

Comment: Just remove it :) It doesn't do anything.

Comment: You mean because it have the same field name, so Automapper itself will figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @LucianBargaoanu I got it working by adding:

```cs
cfg.Advanced.RecursiveQueriesMaxDepth = 1;
```